# Транзакции и блокировки в MySQL

Tags: mysql, транзакции, transaction, блокировки

Всем привет. Перечитал много статей по транзакциям и блокировкам в MySQL, но пока так и не понял, что следует использовать для моего случая. Имеется таблица clients с полем balance, где записан баланс пользователя. Пользователь в интерфейсе вводит сумму, которую хочет списать и в результате поле balance должно быть обновлено для данного клиента. Как защитить себя от того, что два процесса могут одновременно считать и записать данные в одну строку. Таблица InnoDB. Заранее благодарен за помощь в этом вопросе!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует **явная** и **не явная** блокировка.

- Явная используется непосредственно самим механизмом БД при записи, чтений, обновлений данных.
- Не явная блокировка устанавливается напрямую пользователем.

Так как у тебя механизм хранения InnoDB, то неявная блокировка будет происходить на уровне строк.
Если ты хочешь что бы твои данные были правильно записаны и считаны, то перед записью этих данных явно установи блокировку (Устанавливается на всю таблицу). А после сними ее.
Пример:

```
LOCK TABLES clients READ LOCAL;
... производим запись (insert, update)...
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Здесь:

- **LOCK TABLES** - задает блокировку таблицы
- **clients** - имя блокируемой таблицы
- **READ LOCAL** - тип блокировки (блокирует таблицу для чтения, но позволяет осуществлять вставку данных)

P.S [здесь более подробно](https://habrahabr.ru/post/46542/)

Comment: Lukmanov, а почему тип блокировки READ LOCAL? разве не WRITE должен использовать? Ведь если я правильно понял READ LOCAL, если кто то считал таблицу до ее блокировки, то потом этот же процесс сможет обновить данные в ней

Comment: @Baurzhan Лучше не следуйте этому совету. Полная блокировка таблицы, при необходимости изменения одной записи - это стрелять из пушки по воробьям. при блокировки таблицы с ней не сможет работать больше никто. Получайте конкретную запись с балансом пользователя с фразой `for update`, тогда будет заблокирована только эта строка и другой процесс читающий конкретно ее для той же цели будет ждать, остальные работать. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: @Baurzhan, да тебе будет правильнее использовать тип блокировки WRITE. И посмотри на комментарий Mike. Если твоя база данных будет работать в многопользовательской среде с большим числом одновременных транзакций, то лучше использовать for update. И да тебе еще более подробнее нужно рассмотерть случай взаимных блокировок.